# SaveInBackround() is not working for Parse file

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on Parse using Heroku server. last night my Images was uploading fine **(all other data is uploading fine ie string ,int etc)**, but this morning there was an error in uploading images and the error was ie
  **com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Could not store file.**

```
 final ParseObject productDetails = new ParseObject("VendorInv");

        productDetails.put("productMrp", mrp2);
        productDetails.put("productName", name2);
        productDetails.put("productDetails", details2);
       // productDetails.put("size", size2);
        productDetails.put("type", type2);
        productDetails.put("color", color2);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
        cropped.compress(PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

        // Create the ParseFile
        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(name2 + ".png", image,"image/png");
        file.saveInBackground(new ProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                Log.i("Parse", percentDone.toString());
            }
        });
        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    productDetails.put("productImage", file);

                    try {
                        productDetails.save();

                        String obj = productDetails.getObjectId();

                        ParseObject pd = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Vendors", objId);

                        ParseRelation<ParseObject> pr = pd.getRelation("vendorInv");

                        pr.add(ParseObject.createWithoutData("VendorInv", obj));

                        pd.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
                                } else {
                                    Log.i("Parse", e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("sand", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know how to tackle this problem .

Comment: Instead of `Log.i("Parse", e.toString());`, use `e.printStackTrace()` and post the new data. Seems like something related to the db/server

Comment: hey, thanks for answering. Above problem was due to insufficient space on my free sandbox server, and i solved this by using the paid version of mongolab

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be like the same issue posted on their repo: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/670

Quota exceeded for DB storage. Contact your provider to change plans.